# \w is not matching cyrillic characters in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a following regular expression

```
$string=~m/([A-Za-z0-9]+\s?\(\d+(?:,\d+)?\s?(?:(?:\.\.\.)|…)\s?\d+(?:,\d+)?\)\s+[\p{L}%. ]+\s?(?:\W))/;
print "match is '$1'\n";
```

Which I am testing against a string with russian (cyryllic) symbols in it. My example string is

> O2 (0 … 30) % об.д.

It came out of a file encoded in UTF-8. I'm expecting mentioned regular expression to match the whole string, but it is only matches this

```
O2 (0 … 30) %о
```

it is seems that cyrillic  letter 'о' here matces character class \W  rather then \p{L} as I expected. I tried putting mentioned regular expression in a [regular expression tester](https://regex101.com/) and it worked as I expected with the PCRE flavor, but with the others flavor the behavior is the same as I described here.

I tried running regular expression with a /u flag replacing \p{L} with \w but that does not helped. Can you please help figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the output of `sprintf("%vX", $string)`

Comment: The output is "4F.32.20.28.30.20.E2.80.A6.20.33.30.29.20.25.20.D0.BE.D0.B1.2E.D0.B4.2E.3B.43.48.34.20.28.30.2C.34.33.20.2E.2E.2E.20.31.2C.31.29.20.25.D0.BE.D0.B1.2E.D0.B4.2E" the string contains more characters then I posted here, because there others symbols, but at the moment I am concerned with the mentioned part of this string. If needed I can shrink this string to what I posted and provided requested output again

Comment: As long as you made sure the code exhibits the problem with that string, that's all that matters.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't match the unicode part... is there any toggle to specify the use of unicode?

Comment: I tried using /u switch replacing \p{L} with \w but with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a string text encoded using UTF-8.

`\p{L}`, `\W` and such expect to match against Unicode Code Points (decoded text).

Easily fixed:

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $string_ucp = decode_utf8($string_utf8);
if ($string_ucp =~ /.../) {
   print("$1\n");
}
```

Since `…` isn't an ASCII character, you will need to encode your source code using UTF-8 and tell Perl that's what you did using `use utf8;`.

You will need to encode the output you send to STDOUT now that `$1` no longer contains UTF-8. You can do that using `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`. That causes input from STDIN to be automatically decoded, output to STDOUT and STDERR to be automatically decoded, and it changes the default encoding for file handles opened in scope.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not following you. You said that I need to encode my source code using UTF-8, what do you mean by that? My source code file is encoded in UTF-8. I tried using function  decode_utf8 but code does not compile.

Comment: Re "*I tried using function decode_utf8 but code does not compile.*", Woops, forgot to load and import the sub.

Comment: Re "*My source code file is encoded in UTF-8.*", That's what I meant. But you gotta tell Perl you did that by adding `use utf8;`. Perl expects ASCII otherwise.

Comment: Your code works, thank you! Now I am getting expected output. But still I dont understand why it happened. Basically If am getting strings encoded in UTF-8 from a file I need to put 'use utf8' at the top of the source code to make sure that regular expressions works as expected with non Latin characters?

Comment: Decode inputs; encode outputs. If your source code is UTF-8, you need to decode it (`use utf8;`). If you read from a file or STDIN, you need to decode it (`use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`). If you print to a file, STDOUT or STDERR, you need to encode (also covered by `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`).

Comment: OK, things are clearer now, really need to read some manuals so, Thank you very much for your help! Have a good day and upcoming weekends!

Comment: I recommend against the decode_utf8 function from Encode, as it will use the internal Perl `utf8` encoding that does not validate and can result in broken strings. Use `decode 'UTF-8', $str` or [a nicer wrapper from my Encode::Simple module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Simple#decode_utf8).